# Call a function after the directive is loaded angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, timeout

I have a isolated directive, my controller looks like:

```
app.controller('ZacksController', ['$scope', '$http', 'ngDialog', '$timeout', function($scope, $http, ngDialog, $timeout){
     //some code here
}]);
```

The HTML in the file looks like:

```
<div class="income-older-block" ng-show="selectedAge!=1">
     <income-form></income-form>
</div>
```

I have a directive in related HTML folder,

```
app.directive("incomeForm", ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
   function link($scope) {
      var hello = function () {
        alert("1");
      }
      $timeout(hello, 0);
   }


   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: "app/zacks/your-income/income-form/income-form.html",
      link: link,
      controller: function ($scope, $timeout) {
                                  $scope.$watch("zacks.AgeRet.value",function(newValue,OldValue,scope){
                 if (newValue){
                     alert((newValue));
                 }
             });
      }
   }
}]);
```

I want to alert after I load the directive in the page, the alert appears at initial page itself. May I know what to do?

The actual problem is I'm using a rz-slider and want to initialize it once the directive is loaded to DOM., as its not taking the values provided. Is there any other approach for this problem?

```
<rzslider rz-slider-model="zacks.AgeRet.value" rz-slider-floor="zacks.AgeRet.floor" rz-slider-ceil="zacks.AgeRet.ceil"></rzslider>
```

In case if the timeout works, I'm planning to initialize something like this:

```
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.$broadcast('rzSliderForceRender');
});
```

**UPDATE**

Added a controller in the directive, so now I'm able to get the value when I move the slider, but still not able to initialize the value of the slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 2**

HTML:

```
<div class="income-older-block" ng-show="selectedAge!=1">
     <income-form></income-form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('ZacksapiController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', 'ngDialog', '$timeout', 'dataService', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, ngDialog, $timeout, dataService){

$scope.$watch('selectedAge', function(newValue, oldValue) {        
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {           
            $timeout(function() {
                alert("reCalcViewDimensions");
                $scope.$broadcast('rzSliderForceRender'); // This is not working, but alert works.
            }, 0);

    }
});
```

**Update:**

Triggered the window resize event inside the $timeout, but this would be a temporary hack. Would be great if someone help me out with the real approach to solve the problem.

```
$timeout(function() {
     window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
     $scope.$broadcast('rzSliderForceRender');
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I kind of found 2 solutions for these kind of problems, but still not serving the purpose of what I really need with rz-slider.

**Solution 1**

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="ZacksController">
   <after-render after-render="rzSliderForceRender">element</after-render>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.directive('afterRender', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    var def = {
        restrict: 'E',          
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $timeout(scope.$eval(attrs.afterRender), 0);  //Calling a scoped method
        }
    };
    return def;                
}]);

app.controller('ZacksController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '      $timeout', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $timeout){

    $scope.rzSliderForceRender = function()
    {
         alert('Fired!');   
    };
}]);
```